# deep filter a dynamic array of objects (by string property)

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I wanna filter an dynamic array by the property "name".
The array has 3 kinds of objects: "link", "folder" & "app".

```
{
    type: "link",
    name: ""
},
{
    type: "folder",
    name: "",
    childs: []
},
{
    type: "app",
    name: "",
    childs: []
}
```

- *app* can only have *links* as children.
- *folder* can have all 3 kinds (link, folder, app) as children.

If a child matches the search value, all parents of it survive.
(its siblings get filtered out if it they don't match)

---

I have an array somewhat like this:

```
var items = [
    {
        type: 'app',
        name: 'bar',
        childs: [
            {
                type: 'link',
                name: 'mee'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        type: 'folder',
        name: 'fizz',
        childs: [
            {
                type: 'link',
                name: 'buzz'
            },
            {
                type: 'app',
                name: 'boo',
                childs: []
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        type: 'folder',
        name: 'bla',
        childs: [
            {
                type: 'app',
                name: 'blee',
                childs: [
                    {
                        type: 'link',
                        name: 'blee'
                    },
                    {
                        type: 'link',
                        name: 'bar'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                type: 'folder',
                name: 'mee',
                childs: [
                    {
                        type: 'app',
                        name: 'bar',
                        childs: [
                            {
                                type: 'link',
                                name: 'maa'
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        type: 'link',
                        name: 'mee'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        type: 'link',
        name: 'foo',
        childs: [
            {
                type: 'folder',
                name: 'baf',
                childs: []
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

---

I managed to write a **non deep** filtering:
https://jsfiddle.net/6ocd5u8y
*(I would appreciate any suggestions for this code as well)*

I also found code which filters deep, but keeps the siblings of the matching children alive and filters by any string:
https://jsfiddle.net/ndfu8cpL

---

the result for a search like 'bar' should be:

```
filteredArray = [
    {
        type: 'app',
        name: 'bar',
        childs: []
    },
    {
        type: 'folder',
        name: 'bla',
        childs: [
            {
                type: 'app',
                name: 'blee',
                childs: [
                    {
                        type: 'link',
                        name: 'bar'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                type: 'folder',
                name: 'mee',
                childs: [
                    {
                        type: 'app',
                        name: 'bar',
                        childs: []
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

---

I would be very grateful if someone could help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could build new object if the wanted property is found or if the nested array has some items after filtering.

```js
function filter(array, name) {
    return array.reduce((r, o) => {
        var childs = filter(o.childs || [], name);
        if (o.name === name || childs.length) r.push(Object.assign({}, o, { childs }));
        return r;
    }, []);
}

var items = [{ type: 'app', name: 'bar', childs: [{ type: 'link', name: 'mee' }] }, { type: 'folder', name: 'fizz', childs: [{ type: 'link', name: 'buzz' }, { type: 'app', name: 'boo', childs: [] }] }, { type: 'folder', name: 'bla', childs: [{ type: 'app', name: 'blee', childs: [{ type: 'link', name: 'blee' }, { type: 'link', name: 'bar' }] }, { type: 'folder', name: 'mee', childs: [{ type: 'app', name: 'bar', childs: [{ type: 'link', name: 'maa' }] }, { type: 'link', name: 'mee' }] }] }, { type: 'link', name: 'foo', childs: [{ type: 'folder', name: 'baf', childs: [] }] }];

console.log(filter(items, 'bar'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```